# transform JavaScript object with arrays into a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Does anyone have a smart idea how to transform this javascript object into an associative php array?

Note that I don't want to read this into PHP, I want the same data structure in PHP without going through each line and editing it e.g. adding `''` and `=>`.

```
module.exports = {
  base: '/',
  api: {
    sentry: 'https://7ed0a4e5846c4c31a44812bd5e37c2a1@sentry.io/257382',
    wp: {
      imgSize: {
        _380x270: 'medium',
      }
    }
  },
  y: 2017,
  href: {
    authors: '#',
    fb: '#',
    instagram: '#',
    de: 'https://wearede.com/',
  },
  faction: {
    subscribe: "/",
    search: "/",
  },
  search: {
    tags: [{
        t: 'Lifestyle',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'Politics',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'Economy',
        h: '#'
      },
    ],
    articles: [{
        t: 'იოლანდა ჰადიდმა ჯიჯი ჰადიდის და ზეინ მალიკის ერთობლივი ფოტო გამოაქვეყნა',
        h: '#',
      },
      {
        t: 'ლარი ევროსთან მიმართებით რეკორდულად გაუფასურდა',
        h: '#',
      },
    ]
  },
  menuMain: [{
      h: '#',
      t: 'სიახლეები'
    },
    {
      h: '#',
      t: 'ბიზნესი და ტექნოლოგია'
    },
    {
      h: '#',
      t: 'Lifestyle'
    },
    {
      h: '#',
      t: 'მოგზაურობა'
    },
    {
      h: '#',
      t: 'გასტრონომია'
    },
    {
      h: '#',
      t: '<i class="i i--hammock fz-20"></i>'
    },
  ],
  footer: {
    authors: [{
        i: 'https://picsum.photos/55/55',
        h: '#',
        n: 'Rusudan Tinatin',
        t: 'Author',
        d: 'ლარი ევროსთან მიმართებით რეკორდულად გაუფასურდა',
      },
      {
        i: 'https://picsum.photos/55/55',
        h: '#',
        n: 'Rusudan Tinatin',
        t: 'Author',
        d: 'იოლანდა ჰადიდმა ჯიჯი ჰადიდის და ზეინ მალიკის ერთობლივი ფოტო გამოაქვეყნა',
      },
      {
        i: 'https://picsum.photos/55/55',
        h: '#',
        n: 'Rusudan Tinatin',
        t: 'Author',
        d: 'ლარი ევროსთან მიმართებით რეკორდულად გაუფასურდა',
      },
    ],
    nav: [{
        t: 'პირობები',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'პირადი ინფორმაცია',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'ჩვენს შესახებ',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'კონტაქტი',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'ავტორები',
        h: '#'
      },
    ],
    cats: [{
        t: 'სიახლეები',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'Lifestyle',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'გასტრონომია',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'ბიზნესი და ტექნოლოგია',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'მოგზაურობა',
        h: '#'
      },
      {
        t: 'Hammock',
        h: '#'
      },
    ],
    articles: {
      items: articles.slice(0, 3),
      i: 'https://picsum.photos/380/260',
      t: 'დეკანოზი გიორგი მამალაძე სასამართლომ დამნაშავედ ცნო',
      h: '#',
    },
  }
}
```

At the moment I'm considering an option to record macros in vim, but that will take quite some time, and I see potential pitfalls in that approach.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` in Javascript, parse it in PHP with `json_decode()`, then use `var_export()` to print it as a PHP array literal.

Comment: BTW, that's not an array of Javascript objects. It's a single object. Some of the properties contain arrays of objects.

Comment: @Barmar I was missing the knowledge of `var_export()` thanks! also amended question, your right.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I'm fine with you answering. We both thought of it at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar since your both fine, I'm accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert this object into a JSON string. Then in PHP, you can `json_decode` and `var_export`.